# How to solve 'Underflow occurred in computation' when polarplot?

Tags: plotting

I am running below script:

```
PolarPlot[r == Power[Abs[Tan[t]], Abs[Cot[t]]], {t, 0, Pi}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1, Axes -> False, Frame -> False]
```

But I got below:

```
General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation.
```

How to solve this problem and get this plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument in PolarPlot is radius not an equation:

```
PolarPlot[Power[Abs[Tan[t]], Abs[Cot[t]]], {t, 0, Pi }, 
PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1, Axes -> False, Frame -> False]
```

[image]